# Printing from Ios/Ipad Adobe Air 3 application?

Tags: ios, flash, printing, air, adobe

Does anyone have experience with printing from iOs/Adobe Air3 app? Is it possible without need to write native extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible without a Native Extension, though one could be easily written for it.

[Link to Adobe Live Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html)

It says: **Mobile Browser Support: This class is not supported in mobile browsers**